# Joomla! 2.5 Component menu type parameter in the generated URL

Tags: php, joomla, components, joomla-k2

I am modifing K2 itemslist->category view in order to supply also a tag and so shown articles will be the one of specified category and view.

My question is: **How to add a menu parameter to the menu type wich will insert its own value on item URL?**

In my case generated menu type url is

"index.php?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&layout=category&task=category&id=1&tag="

I don't understand why tag is blank.

[here it is my category.xml](https://gist.github.com/4484243)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters taken into the URL are those specified within the request fields and fieldset

```
<fields name="request">
    <fieldset name="request">
        <!-- Matt93 added this line. -->
        <field name="tag" type="tag" default="" label="K2_SELECT_TAG" description=""/>
        <!-- end -->
        <field name="task" type="hidden" default=""/>
        <field name="id" type="hidden" default=""/>
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

You correctly added the tag field here, but it has a default value of "" which means no value. This is exactly what you see in your URL (no value). Try setting a different default value and you will see it in your URL.
Also you have set the tag field in almost every fieldset. Remove all except the one in the request fieldset.